# I upgraded the GAE in Eclipse to 1.7.4

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

My JSP based application now doesn't deploy. I get the following error:
*Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.*
Has anyone found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are using some Java code in your JSP as a result of which the JDK is needed to compile that.

Here are some points that you can try:

- Check that you are using a JDK and not a JRE. In Eclipse, go to Window --> Preferences and then Java --> Installed JREs. If it is pointing to a JRE and not JDK, I suggest you change that. So install a JDK, remove references to the JRE in the settings here and point it to the JDK only.
- If you are still getting the exception above, then I suggest to provide the `-vm`setting in `eclipse.ini` which is found in the same folder as your Eclipse executable.

Comment: 2 or 3 weeks ago i had the same error. The eclipse.ini trick solved the problem for me (but its important that you add the path to your JDK!!). http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini